# How to reuse hash table in SAS

Tags: sas

I have many large_tables (billions of lines), which I want to subset based on an id_list (millions of lines). I'm using a hash table to speed it up:

```
data subset1;
    set large_table1;
    if _n_ eq 1 then do;
        declare hash ht(dataset:"id_list");
        ht.definekey('id');
        ht.definedone();
    end;
    if ht.check() eq 0 then do; output; end;
run;
```

How can I reuse id_list's hash table? Recreating it in each subset query wastes too much time.

**Update:** As shown in the answers, currently there's no workaround to make persistent hash tables in SAS. I tested empirically two less optimal options with a 12mn lines id_list and 1.5bn lines large_table. Using format instead of hash table took almost double the time (40 minutes vs. 23 minutes). This makes the overhead of recreating the hash table in each data step negligible, therefore I'll just do that for the time being.

Comment: Loading a hash table with 1m+ cardinality should not take too much time.  Can you show the log for a step that only loads the hash ?  Writing the output data set is probably what is taking the most time.  If the id_list has millions of ids, does large_table have billions of rows ?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, hash tables cannot persist across DATA steps. AFAIK, when the step ends they are erased to free the memory. I saw a talk by Art Carpenter at SGF 2018 where he tried different ways to trick SAS into making a persistent hash table, and could not succeed.

https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2018/2399-2018.pdf

Answer (score 3):

For completeness; this is how you'd re-use the hash: using FCMP.  It doesn't truly reuse the table in a data step (it will re-load the hash table), but in a macro it does persist.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.func;
function check_ids( name $ );
 declare hash h_ids(dataset:"work.class_names");
 rc = h_ids.defineKey( "name");
 rc = h_ids.definedone();
 rc = h_ids.check();
 return( not rc );
endsub;

quit;

data class_names;
  set sashelp.class;
  where sex='F'; 
run;

 options cmplib=work.funcs;

data class_find_f;
   set sashelp.class;
   if check_ids(name)=1;
run;
```

See [Hashing in PROC FCMP to Enhance Your Productivity](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/129-2013.pdf) for more details on hashing in FCMP.

Comment: Is this re-using the hash object itself, or just the code to generate it?

Comment: Afaik with this you still can't use multiple data steps, could you please clarify @Joe?

Comment: @WillianRazente The hash table isn't stored, yes (see Quentin's answer for details on that), just reused in structure.  However, it is reusable if it's used in macro language (with `%sysfunc`).  I'll edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd do it is not to use a hash table, but to use a `format`.

```
data for_fmt;
  set id_list;
  retain fmtname 'idlistf' type 'n'; *or c if id is character, and add $ to fmtname;
  start=id;
  label=1;
  output;
  if _n_=1 then do;  *this section we tell it what to do with 'other' (not found) IDs;
    hlo='o';
    call missing(start); *unneeded but I like to do this for clarity;
    label=0;
    output;
  end;
run;

*if ID can be duplicated, then run a proc sort nodupkey here;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
run;
```

This persists and should be as fast as your hash table.  If your ID list is very large you can use a `view` here and only process it one time.

Comment: What is SAS's format data structure type (e.g. hash table, b-tree...)? Is it built when I run proc format? Is it built only once, no matter how many times I apply it, even in different data steps? Does achieve O(1) search complexity after all?

Comment: I believe formats are binary tree. Yes they are built only once, when PROC FORMAT runs, and are saved in a SAS catalog.  Formats can be built once, and used in different steps, even different sessions if you save them in a permanent catalog file.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to test empirically for my use case whether formats with reuse and O(logn) are quicker than hash tables with no reuse and O(1) on average... Thanks!

Comment: I tested both approaches and, for my use case, hash tables are almost twice as fast as formats. I updated the question to talk about that

Answer (score 1):

You could also load the smaller dataset into memory using the `SASFILE` statement.

http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsglobal&docsetTarget=n0osyhi338pfaan1plin9ioilduk.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

This would speed up the load each time as it would be loading from memory to memory, rather than from disk to memory...